# Use XSLT to group and sum a value

Tags: xml, xslt, key

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<Shipment xmlns="http://oracle.com/EbizGateway/NA/SynchASN/V2">
    <containerDetails>
        <ContainerID>C123</ContainerID>
        <DeliveryContainer>
            <ContainerType>Plastic</ContainerType>
            <PackedOrder>
                <OrderNumber>O1234</OrderNumber>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A123</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>123</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>3</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A123</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>123</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>2</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A234</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>234</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>2</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
            </PackedOrder>
    </DeliveryContainer>
    </containerDetails>
</Shipment>
```

I need to group each PackedItem based on the ContainerID,suppliernumber,customernumner,ShippedQuantity.

Once grouped I need to add up the Shipped quantities for all the duplicate occurences of PackedItem. For eg:

```
ContainerID     suppliernumber      customernumber      ShippedQuantity
C123                A123                    123                     3
C123                A123                    123                     2
C123                A234                    234                     2
```

Since the first two occurences are duplicate so the quantity needs to be added
This has to be transformed as below

```
ContainerID     suppliernumber      customernumber       ShippedQuantity
C123                A123                    123                     5
C123                A234                    234                     2
```

After adding up the quantities I need to update the ShippedQuantity in both the duplicate occurrences as shown in the xml below. Apart from ShippedQuantity rest of the values are to be copied as it is.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<Shipment xmlns="http://oracle.com/EbizGateway/NA/SynchASN/V2">
    <containerDetails>
        <ContainerID>C123</ContainerID>
        <DeliveryContainer>
            <ContainerType>Plastic</ContainerType>
            <PackedOrder>
                <OrderNumber>O1234</OrderNumber>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A123</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>123</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>5</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A123</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>123</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>5</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
                <PackedItem>
                    <controldata>
                        <suppliernumber>A234</suppliernumber>
                        <customernumner>234</customernumner>
                    </controldata>
                    <ShipmentDetails>
                        <ShippedQuantity>2</ShippedQuantity>
                    </ShipmentDetails>
                </PackedItem>
            </PackedOrder>
    </DeliveryContainer>
    </containerDetails>
</Shipment>
```

I tried many options, but cant really understand how to populate the sum of the shippedquantities in every duplicate packedItem. :( PFB the xslt below where i tried the same.. it does not work though..

```
<xsl:key name="ContRef" match="tns:PackedItem"
    use="concat(../../../tns:ContainerID,../../tns:ContainerType,./tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber,./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner,./tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity,' ',generate-id(./ancestor::tns:containerDetails))"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:Shipment>
      <xsl:for-each select="/tns:Shipment">
        <xsl:for-each select="./tns:containerDetails/tns:DeliveryContainer/tns:PackedOrder/tns:PackedItem[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID,../../tns:ContainerType,./tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber,./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner,./tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity,' ',generate-id(./ancestor::tns:containerDetails))))]">
          <xsl:variable name="ContID"
            select="../../../tns:ContainerID"/>
          <xsl:variable name="CustPartNumber"
            select="./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner"/>

          <xsl:variable name="SuppPartNumber"
            select="./tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber"/>

          <xsl:variable name="ShippedQty"
            select="./tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity"/>

          <!-- calculate total shipped quantity-->
           <xsl:variable name="TotalShippedQuantity"
            select="sum(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID,../../tns:ContainerType,./tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber,./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner,./tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity,' ',generate-id(./ancestor::tns:containerDetails)))/tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity)"/>

          <!-- populate the total shipped quantity in each duplicate packed item -->
          <xsl:for-each select="../tns:PackedItem[./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner=$CustPartNumber and ./tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber=$SuppPartNumber and ./tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity=$ShippedQty]/tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity">
                        <xsl:text>inside for</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$TotalShippedQuantity"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:Shipment>
  </xsl:template>
```

Please advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259342/how-to-group-data-from-one-xml-to-other-using-xslt#comment44879293_28259342

Comment: PFA the xslt (that i tried) in my question above. I would be very thankful for any hints on this one.

Comment: I am able to calculate the sum now with the following modification in my xslt. However still have no idea of how to populate this value in duplicate PackedItems and copy the rest of the payload as it is. <xsl:variable name="TotalShippedQuantity"
             select="sum(../tns:PackedItem[./tns:controldata/tns:customernumner=$CustPartNumber]/tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity)"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by each `PackedItem` based on the `ContainerID`, `suppliernumber` and `customernumner` then the key should look like this....

```
<xsl:key name="ContRef"  
     match="tns:PackedItem"
     use="concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner)"/>
```

Then, to get the distinct items in the group, you do this:

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="//tns:PackedItem
             [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner)[1]))]">
```

And to get the sum of the `ShippedQuantity`, you can use the `sum` function to sum all the relevant groups in the current key

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="sum(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner))/tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity)" />
```

Try this XSLT for starters

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://oracle.com/EbizGateway/NA/SynchASN/V2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="ContRef" 
         match="tns:PackedItem"
         use="concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tns:Shipment>
    <xsl:for-each select="//tns:PackedItem[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner)[1]))]">
      <!-- populate the total shipped quantity in each duplicate packed item -->
      <tns:PackedItems>
        <tns:ContainerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../tns:ContainerID" />
        </tns:ContainerID>
        <tns:suppliernumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber" />
        </tns:suppliernumber>
        <tns:customernumner>
            <xsl:value-of select="tns:controldata/tns:customernumner" />
        </tns:customernumner>
        <tns:ShippedQuantity>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('ContRef',concat(../../../tns:ContainerID, '|', tns:controldata/tns:suppliernumber, '|', tns:controldata/tns:customernumner))/tns:ShipmentDetails/tns:ShippedQuantity)" />
        </tns:ShippedQuantity>
      </tns:PackedItems>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tns:Shipment>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for replying. I tried using the xslt as suggested in your post.. but that throws error in the "for-each" statement stating "The value is not a node-set"

Comment: Take a look at http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJm which shows the XSLT in my answering working happily. Thanks!